# Get 'translateX' position in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This code sets the translateX position:

```
 var pos = -500px;
 $(.slide).css('-webkit-transform',  "translateX(" + pos+ "px)");
```

but, the following code does not get the translateX position:

```
 var currTrans = $(".slide").css('-webkit-transform', "translateX()");
```

Why? What is the correct way to get the value then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
var pos = -500;
 $('.slide').css('-webkit-transform',  'translateX(' + pos+ 'px)');

var currTrans = $('.slide').css('-webkit-transform').split(/[()]/)[1];
var posx = currTrans.split(',')[4];
```

Upadate:

Demo link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/ax5nM/)

Comment: the output is 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)' then how to extract TranslateX position?

Comment: Still the output is same

Comment: Not positive, but I don't think the webkit prefix is needed anymore with updated versions of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var currTrans = $('.slide').css("transform").split(",")[4].trim()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what the OP is requesting, but comes close.
OP's code is setting a transform with an empty translateX directive; instead, the code should use $('.slide').css("transform") to get the full value of the 'transform' property and then use split to break it into the individual transforms. After doing .split() there could be zero or many directives to look at and parse, and it's also possible that pairing another transform with it could affect the X offset and make it visually different from the translateX value, so be careful for that.