# how to get css translate value and make into contidion with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to get value from css and make it into condition, I dont know if its posibble or not. I wanted to get translateX value and check if value is 200% show pop up.

or is there any other way to doing this?
thank you

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.box').css("transform", "translateX(" + sTop + "%)");
  if ($('.box').css("transform", "translateX") === 200) {
    alert('pop');
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got two problems. Firstly you need to use the getter of `css()` in the `if` statement, eg `.css('transform')`. Secondly that will return you a string in this format which you'll need to dissect to get the value you need: `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 15.9, 0)`

Comment: is there easy way just get transform value?.I did try get value such as marginTop and display, and it work well. But its kinda confusing to get transform value

Comment: You could use a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21522812/519413

Answer (score 0):

Just like hinted from the comments (which I cannot write yet): http://jsfiddle.net/ax5nM/107/

```
var t=$(".box").css('transform').split(/[()]/)[1].split(',');
var m="X: " + t[4] + "px; Y: " + t[5] + "px; (" + t +")";
$(".msg").text( m ).fadeIn();
if (t[4] >= 20 && !popped) {
    popped=true;
  alert('pop');
}
```

this pops for me after scrolling a bit.